# How to use a Code-First approach with Entity Framework to insert a complex class created from an XML Doc

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization

My client is migrating from a web based CRM who has only provided them a XML export of their data.

The export is 190k line long with many nested objects.

I tried many online tools to try and convert the XML to a usable class in C# with limited success, including trying to convert it to JSON to use QuickType.IO to no avail.

My aim is to use Entity Framework (to which I have only used in it's most basic form) to create a SQL Server database from the XML file to allow me to integrate it and insert records into their new SQL Server based CRM.

I used Visual Studio "Paste Special > XML as Classes" which seemed to do the best job of creating the classes. However, due to the XML format of the export it created classes like this:

```
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class exportContactActivitiesCall
    {

        private object[] itemsField;

        private ItemsChoiceType4[] itemsElementNameField;

        private uint idField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("comments", typeof(exportContactActivitiesCallComments))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("dateoccured", typeof(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("details", typeof(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("duration", typeof(byte))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("id", typeof(uint))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parent", typeof(uint))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("timerecords", typeof(exportContactActivitiesCallTimerecords))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("type", typeof(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
        public object[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public ItemsChoiceType4[] ItemsElementName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsElementNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsElementNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public uint id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema = false)]
    public enum ItemsChoiceType4
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        comments,

        /// <remarks/>
        dateoccured,

        /// <remarks/>
        details,

        /// <remarks/>
        duration,

        /// <remarks/>
        id,

        /// <remarks/>
        parent,

        /// <remarks/>
        timerecords,

        /// <remarks/>
        type,
    }
```

I have tried using XmlSerializer and EF like this:

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(export));

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("content.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                var result = (export)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);


                using (var ctx = new ExportContext())
                {

                    ctx.Export.AddRange(result.contact);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
```

While this seems to create a Database without errors, it only imported the ID Field for each record.

I have started converting the classes that Visual Studio created into objects instead of the itemChoiceType enum. And while I am getting success with this it it will likely take me some time to complete.

I thought this may be a good opportunity to delve into the world of Entity and see if anyone knows if Entity could infact do what I require.

Or if anyone knows of a good way to achieve what I am aiming to do.